# In wpf ,I need to use a flag to decide to use default contextmenu or my customized contextmenu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, contextmenu

In my project ,I use wpf to create a UI. For the textboxes on the UI, I want to customize their context menus. however A new requirement asks me to switch context menu more flexibility , I need to use a flag in my view modelto decide to use default context menu or customized context menu. My original code is like below

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource itemStyle}"/>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

MenuItems is thedata in view model 
Now I want to use a flag in view model to implement the new requirement ,any suggestions on this issue?

Comment: What have you tried already. First thought is a bool in your ViewModel and a ContextMenu which depends on the value of the bool.

Comment: Actually I tried to write some code in back end of the textbox to create a new context menu to show my customized context menu . But it looks like I use different context menu to show . And the code became a little be tricky. I am still trying to find another way to do that